# How to maintain uniqueness of primary key column in multiple client single server application

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, primary-key, guid

I have found a number of different questions on generating UID, But couldn't satisfied with my requirements, please find below my business requirement.

our application has the main database that resides on SQL server on the server. We have the same application hosted on a clients machine with the same database structure that is available on a server. Client application runs on local machine and updates data on local machine database now after every 15 minutes client machine database sync with server machine database and updates data on the server database.

Currently, I have implemented int as primary key with auto identity true. Now let say client 1 and client 2 are generating same primary key for example "1,2,3.. so
on" on their local database So, now when data sync with server database then it will conflict with primary unique constraint.

So, now my question is how to over come from this scenario. how to generate a unique key that is globally unique without any duplication. As per my knowledge related to GUID. In this scenario, GUID will be going to generate from a different machine so there will be the possibility of duplication of GUID.

Please help me out with the best solution which I can implement to achieve uniqueness with different the machine.

Comment: One possible solution is you have unique Ids for your clients and on the server's database you can have composite PK with client Id + client table primary key as the key.

Comment: @Hakunamatata Yes, I already thought about the composite primary key but if someone has an easy way to handle this scenario then I am happy to implement that rather than use a composite primary key. Thanks for your comment

Comment: From what you've explained, simply use an identity in the target table as the primary key and preserve the key from local system in the table as a n attribute (one that is obviously not unique). Also include whatever you want to use from the source system as an identifier (host name? mac address?) I don't see any explanation of the purpose of your central unique key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the .Net GUID generator, you will have no problem.

```
Guid.NewGuid();
```

Essentially as described [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080627-00/?p=21823/), the GUID is partly based on the computers MAC address, which is usually unique, unless someone has been copying addresses.  So two different computers can never generate the same GUID.

Comment: The only problem is, that GUID is quite bad primary key, so there would be some overhead due to this.

Comment: @AntonínLejsek   True, I never use GUID as a primary key myself.  But if you read the OP's question, he seems to think generating GUID from separate machines ran the risk of duplicate GUID.  I was merely answering that if he uses .Net GUID generator, this is NOT the case.

Comment: @AntonínLejsek I know using GUID as a primary key is a bad idea but could you please suggest is there another way of achieving my functionality without a composite primary key.

Comment: @NirajTrivedi I don't suppose you have access to a Web Server?  One very simple solution would be to create a Web Service accessible by both client and your machines, whose sole purpose was to provide successive integer keys.  The Web Server need not run Sql-Server - any db would do, Postgres, MySQL etc.  All it needs is one field in one table and a GetNextID function.

Comment: @JonathanWillcock Yes you are right web service can help me out. but what if the client is not connected to the internet so it can't access web service and the client can't processed

Comment: @NirajTrivedi Client must have internet access, otherwise how is it updating your server database????

Comment: @JonathanWillcock It will updating server database after each half an hour using Microsoft Synchronization framework if it has a connection or it will try again ......

Comment: @NirajTrivedi OK then you have to do one step more.  If the client needs new id and has no internet connection, then it adds its own id, and stores it as well in a IDPending table.  Then next time client has connection it first loops through IDPending table, calling GetNextID and updates its own keys, before flushing the IDPending table.  After it has done this, then it can safely go ahead and synchronize.

Comment: @JonathanWillcock Yes, that one is good idea. thanks for your all suggestions

Answer (score 0):

### Solution:

It would help to know what the SQL server type is, but regardless almost all SQL servers have a feature called auto increment which can be applied to a column and will automatically select a column value for you based on the previous IDs. You could also in your application have a private integer accessible by all threads that contains the last used ID. Either should work.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to think that all the data from the source databases needs to slot in nicely (and uniquely) into the target database. You haven't explained why this is.

Simply use an identity in the target table as the primary key and preserve the key from local system in the table as an attribute (one that is obviously not unique).

Also include whatever you want to use from the source system as an identifier (host name? mac address?)

Now you have a unique key in your central database, and a way to track a record back to the original system.

If you have any other requirements please explain them